# keyboard options on EditText

Tags: android

On IOS I can place a Done button or any other options above the keyboard view on a text field when that field become active.

How can I do something similar on Android?

Answer (score 0):

In android similar action can be achieved by [android:imeOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:imeOptions) attribute.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etEmail"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:imeActionId="@integer/send"
  android:imeActionLabel="@+string/send_label"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
 android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
```

If you want handle the event you can use `OnEditorActionListener`

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
   //do your stuff here
   return true;
}
return false;
} 
});
```

Comment: How do I add my own custom one?

Comment: AFAIK you can't . Maybe this will be possible if you create a Custom Keyboard.